# c# - SQL command taking precendence, need to run command prior to executing sql command

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

Is there a way to do this? I cannot seem to find anything online regarding this.

If I run the code below the SQL command will execute prior to hiding the div tag, when ideally I would like the div tag to be hidden and then have the `SqlCommand` execute.

```
protected void RunStoredProcedure_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        div.Visible = false;

        Connection.Open();

        SqlCommand StoredProcedure = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure", Connection);
        StoredProcedure.CommandTimeout = 0;
        StoredProcedure.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        StoredProcedure.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date", DateForStoredProcedure.Text));    // DateForStoredProcedure.Text));

        StoredProcedure.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Connection.Close();

        string queryAdditionalFilters = "where user = '" + user.Value + "'";
        generateTagsForLiteral(queryAdditionalFilters);
}
```

Edit: Not sure why this was downvoted as it was marked as answered below with the answer shown below. Whoever downvoted me it would have been helpful to know why as I feel this is a very clear question that way in the future I can post questions correctly or in a preferred fashion.

Comment: What is calling this method?

Comment: before writing your SqlCommand code, check if div.Visible is false: `if(!div.Visible)`

Comment: I think you are missing the fundamentals of server/client behavior. Setting a server div visibility to false will have no effect on the actual div in the client browser until after the server is done executing and returns results to the client. If you want to hide the div on the client, use javascript prior to initiating the server call that results in the invocation of the above code.

Comment: @Theo if I place a javascript call prior to it the SQL command still executes first. So if I added:
[code]
"Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "dialogPopUpVerify()", true);"[/code]

It would still run the SQL command prior to the java code.

Comment: @ElenaDBA I tried that before posting, sadly it does not work.

Comment: @Theo I think I got it, I did not think to do that first :/ Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's the part you are missing. The code you are expecting to execute on the client is not executing until the SQL is complete and the server sends it back to the client to be executed. You need to hide the dive before the post back occurs.

Comment: Ok, great :) glad that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Theo assisting.

The answer was to use javascript to first hide the tag, and then call the c# button click event.